# html attribute and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So is like this , I have few html element like `<div class="mainitem" data-id="123456"></div>` with different attribute `data-id`. Then, have a `button` for calling `ajax`. When I hover the `mainitem` , I also add `data-id` to the `button`. So actually like this:

```
$(".somebtnname").click(function(){
    var dataid = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
       url: base_url + "someapi/" + dataid,
       cache: false,
       type: "GET",
       success: (
          function (html) {
                 //some result   
          })
    });
});
```

I have checked in console everytime I hover `mainitem` the `data-id` have added to `button`.So I think that the `data-id` is different for me to do `ajax`, BUT when I hover first `mainitem` and click `button`, then hover second `mainitem` and click, the `ajax` result is same as first `maintiem`. So I confuse about the `data-id` did not change when `ajax`.

Comment: how are you setting the `data-id`, are you using `data('id', value)` or `attr()` method

Comment: I pass like this `$(".somebtnname').attr("data-id",value)`

Comment: From your description, you are using `.attr('data-id', value)` to set the value and is using `data('id')` to read it, so use the `data()` api to set the value as well - `$(".somebtnname').data("id",value)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes you are saying it right

Comment: @ArunPJohny so I should use `data()` to pass value not `attr()` ?

Comment: you should use attr since you use attr when setting it

Comment: You should use same method while getting and setting the value... either `attr()` or `data()` but same in both the places

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks you I learned =)